Sticky wood surface after applying Tung oil
I applied tung oil to my wood outdoor table after sanding with 150 and 220 sandpaper. The surface has remained on the tacky side.
Should I use a citrus cleaner or a 400 grit sandpaper and then reapply?

Welcome to WSE! How long has the finish been on? As far as I know, tung oil can take very long to cure. Also, just to check, are you expecting any level of protection against the elements with this finish? It seems like an unusual choice for an outdoor table.

In addition to the Q&A linked above, we also have this one which may have additional useful details for you, Tung oil does not dry
